# node reciving an unhandled error event need some insite?

Tags: node.js

I've searched Hi and Low through web sites and docs, and I've yet to figure out why Im getting this error. Yes I'm new to node. I thought id ask here as a last resort.

the error I'm receiving is:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:668:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:789:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/mnt/sdc/opt/codeWork/ReactBuilds/be_full-stack/app.js:10:9)
    at Server.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:874:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:727:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Here's my code I'm running node v14.16.0

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url === '/') {
        res.end('Welcome to our home page')
    }
    if(req.url === '/about') {
        res.end('Here is our short history')
    }
    res.end(`
    <h1>Ooops</h1>
    <p>This is not the page you are looking for</p>
    <a href="/">backHome</a>
    `)
})

server.listen(5000)
```

any incites are very welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should introduce early returns in your code so that you don't call `res.end` multiple times when one of the conditions evaluates to `true` with your request handler still handling `404`:

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === "/") {
    return res.end("Welcome to our home page");
  }
  if (req.url === "/about") {
    return res.end("Here is our short history");
  }
  res.end(`
    <h1>Ooops</h1>
    <p>This is not the page you are looking for</p>
    <a href="/">backHome</a>
  `);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your time.  I would get the error or refresh and after "/" but too new to dissect the error code properly, Thank you.